# jquery nth child - why use li instead of ol in this case?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the following HTML (provided by codecademy):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>Start with the function keyword</li>
            <li>Inputs go between ()</li>
            <li>Actions go between {}</li>
            <li>jQuery is for chumps!</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Inputs are separated by commas.</li>
    <li>Inputs can include other functions!</li>
</ul>
```

The task was to fade out the fourth item in the ordered list, which reads "jQuery is for chumps!". The following was marked as correct:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $target = $("li:nth-child(4)");
    $target.fadeOut('fast');
});
```

My question is why do I use `li:nth-child(4)` instead of `ol:nth-child(4)`? It seems to me like the latter says that I am removing the fourth child of the parent, which is `ol`. However, this just removes the ordered list entirely. Can someone explain how this works?

Comment: Well you can translate li:nth-child(4) to something like: li element which is 4th child of its parent

Comment: `li:nth-child(4)` means "select all `li` which are the 4th child of their parent". If you want "select the 4th child of all `ol`", that would be `ol > :nth-child(4)`.

Comment: @Oriol, thanks for that. Simple explanation that made sense.

Answer (score 0):

`nth-child()` is used to check the parent element and then find the child elements in the order.

So `li:nth-child(4)` is used to check the list item's parent which is `ol` and then check if the list item is 4th child of the ol.

If you use `ol:nth-child(4)` in this case, then it will calculate to fadeout the whole unordered list which is the 4th child of the parent element i.e. `li`(Grandparent)

Notice in the below example, I have added three more `ol` tags for CSS to calculate `ol:nth-child(4)`

```css
li:nth-child(4) {
  color: red; /* Select all list items which are 4th child item */
}

ol:nth-child(4) {
  color: lightblue; /* Select all unordered lists which are 4th child item */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>Start with the function keyword</li>
      <li>Inputs go between ()</li>
      <li>Actions go between {}</li>
      <li>jQuery is for chumps!</li>
    </ol>
     <ol>
      <li>Start with the function keyword</li>
      <li>Inputs go between ()</li>
      <li>Actions go between {}</li>
      <li>jQuery is for chumps!</li>
    </ol>
     <ol>
      <li>Start with the function keyword</li>
      <li>Inputs go between ()</li>
      <li>Actions go between {}</li>
      <li>jQuery is for chumps!</li>
    </ol>
     <ol>
      <li>Start with the function keyword</li>
      <li>Inputs go between ()</li>
      <li>Actions go between {}</li>
      <li>jQuery is for chumps!</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Inputs are separated by commas.</li>
  <li>Inputs can include other functions!</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example @manoj. I can see the difference between those 2 cases with that.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

> Because jQuery's implementation of :nth- selectors is strictly derived
>   from the CSS specification

you should look at CSS specification of this selector. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) gives you the answer:

> The :nth-child(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
>   an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive
>   or zero value for n, and has a parent element. More simply stated, the
>   selector matches a number of child elements whose numeric position in
>   the series of children matches the pattern an+b.

In short, it takes the parent element of the currently "selected" one and searches for the children which include your element as well.

Actually I like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) explanation more:

> The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth
>   child, regardless of type, of its parent.